# User speed in expo has low Accuracy

Tags: react-native

So im trying to find out my user speed and when he stopped so i can take the coordinates.My problem is that the accuracy of 'expo-location' is sooo low.The user stops and the location speed still gives me like 18 m / per hour  .

Here is my code  :

```
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null)
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null)
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null)
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(null)

  

    useEffect(() => 
      async () => {

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({})
        setTimeout(()=>{

          console.log("Latitude : ", location.coords.latitude)
          console.log("Longitude : ", location.coords.longitude)
          console.log("Speed : ", location.coords.speed)

          if(location.coords.speed <= 4 && location.coords.speed != 0  && location.coords.speed != null){
      
            setLocation(location)
            setLatitude(location.coords.latitude)
            setLongitude(location.coords.longitude)
            setSpeed(location.coords.speed)

            return ; 
          }
        },3000)
      
    });

    
    console.log("Final location : ",location)
    console.log("Final speed : ",speed)
    console.log("Final latitude : ",latitude)
    console.log("Final lonitude : ",longitude)
```

Comment: set the options for getCurrentPositionAsync https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationoptions

Comment: I put accuracy also inside the function but same random numbers appear .

Comment: what do you mean by random numbers? did you use the constants, i.e `accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,`? [doc](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#accuracy)

Comment: Hello again,sorry for the late answer , yes i did it that way but still returning like 100 ,after that 50, then is lowing(which in my case is good) and after that suddenly hit like 128 for no reason.I try to simulate a specific route with android simulator.Its because of the specific android phone maybe ?

Comment: My goal is to understand when the user stops , like to have 0 speed or somehting like that .

Comment: could be, if you need precision speed and its not working on all the vendor codes location api's and its options and you have tried and on different phones with actual hardware then open an issue with the vendor, be sure to look at other issues like https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10756